# C# Swagger Generation for enum with default value

Tags: c#, enums, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have the api looks like the following:

```
public Task<IActionResult> GetAsync([FromRoute] string id, [FromQuery] Query select = Query.All)
```

For querys we only want to allow certain properties, listed in the Query enum as below:

```
    public enum Query
    {
        All,
        Property1,
        Property2
    }
```

I added

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>{c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();})
```

in startup.cs, but this does not work for the default value, I get the following generated swagger, default value is 0 instead of a string:

```
     {
        "name": "selec",
        "in": "query",
        "description": "",
        "required": false,
        "type": "string",
        "default": 0, //NOT SHOWN AS STRING
        "enum": [
          "none",
          "property1",
          "property2"
        ]
      },
```

How should I make the default value show as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project is automatically deserializing according to your application's serialization settings, the work around is to add the tag that changes the serialization of that specific property

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
```

Edit: On the startup you can inject your json options to serialize the enums to strings like so:

```
 services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter(true));
                });
```

Comment: where would i add this tag? When I look at the SDK swagger generates I see this in there, but I don't see how i would add it to the code such that it gets serialized correctly

Comment: @BenZifkin this approach is right on top of your Class Property that matches the enum. for startup configuration check the edit